# How would I create an input mask for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vba

Someone asked me if we can create a simple input mask for geodatabase feature classes so that editing of attributes becomes easier. I am however not sure how this works with ArcGIS 10.x Is this possible with VBA or do I need 3rd Party tools to create masks? The last time I did something similar I could only create tools and toolbars...but no window controls...How could this be done now?

Comment: How would the mask interact with editing attributes?

Comment: I was thinking of a window which offers a combo for available Feature classes, then the left hand side shows the field names, and aligned right the textboxes in which the attributes can be either entered for free text, or chosen if they are domains/subtypes.

Comment: Your comment content would be useful as an edit to your Question.  Perhaps with a graphic to illustrate what you are envisaging.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do what you asked based on the "attribute editing" button on the editing toolbar. It gives you a list of all selected features, and you can either change all attributes at once or select the features one by one. On the layer properties (right click > properties > Field) you can define aliases for your fields and make only a subset visible.

If you combine this with [domains and subtypes](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/data_management_toolbox/attribute_domains_and_subtypes.htm) then you have the ability to use default values for new features as well as drop-down menus for "constraint" encoding.

Finally, I sometimes use definition queries (for instance on required fields) to show only the features that have not been updated.